# Azure Functions unit-testing errors (TimerTrigger. HttpFunction)

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, testing, azure-functions

I am currently following this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function) for adding testing to my Azure Functions application.

Currently I have built out 8 Azure Functions which all work well, I have also added a Functions.Tests project and referenced the Azure Functions project within it.

[image]

Here is what the Functions.Tests currently look like.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xunit;

namespace Functions.Tests
{
public class FunctionsTests
{
    private readonly ILogger logger = TestFactory.CreateLogger();

    [Fact]
    public async void Http_trigger_should_return_known_string()
    {
        var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest("name", "Bill");
        var response = (OkObjectResult)await HttpFunction.Run(request, logger);
        Assert.Equal("Hello, Bill", response.Value);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestFactory.Data), MemberType = typeof(TestFactory))]
    public async void Http_trigger_should_return_known_string_from_member_data(string queryStringKey, string queryStringValue)
    {
        var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(queryStringKey, queryStringValue);
        var response = (OkObjectResult)await HttpFunction.Run(request, logger);
        Assert.Equal($"Hello, {queryStringValue}", response.Value);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Timer_should_log_message()
    {
        var logger = (ListLogger)TestFactory.CreateLogger(LoggerTypes.List);
        TimerTrigger.Run(null, logger);
        var msg = logger.Logs[0];
        Assert.Contains("C# Timer trigger function executed at", msg);
    }
}
}
```

However I am getting the following errors within FunctionsTests.cs

[image]

I have tried all the suggested fixes from Visual Studio and checked resources online but with no luck. Perhaps I am missing a reference? I'm not sure as I have followed the guide word for word.

Example Azure Function used:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Exemplar
{
public static class getCase
{
    [FunctionName("getCase")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/case/caseId")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `HttpFunction` and `TimerTrigger` in this case are the Azure functions being tested. What is the name or your function class? That is what you should use. Also avoid using `async void` refactor those tests to use `async Task`

Comment: @Nkosi I have a c# project called Examples with several Functions such as getEntity. In that case, would HttpFunction change to Examples.getEntity.Run?

Comment: Yes that would be the case. [edit] one of the functions into the question so we can show you how to test it. Are they static or instance functions?

Comment: @Nkosi Have tried to replace HttpFunction with a relevant function from my application however VS will only recongise the project "Exemplar" and not the azurefunctions within it.

Comment: @Nkosi Was able to successfuly replace TimerTrigger with Exemplar.getCase.Run, however HttpFunction is not accepting a similar replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming provided project that contains the function is referenced, the test simply needs to arrange and exercise the target function as shown in the linked example

```
[Fact]
public async Task getCase_should_return_known_string()
{
    var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest("name", "Bill");
    var response = (OkObjectResult)await getCase.Run(request, logger);
    Assert.Equal("Hello, Bill", response.Value);
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestFactory.Data), MemberType = typeof(TestFactory))]
public async Task getCase_should_return_known_string_from_member_data(string queryStringKey, string queryStringValue)
{
    var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(queryStringKey, queryStringValue);
    var response = (OkObjectResult)await getCase.Run(request, logger);
    Assert.Equal($"Hello, {queryStringValue}", response.Value);
}
```

Also avoid using `async void`. Refactor those tests to use `async Task` instead.

Comment: This works, I wasn't using the correct values as you described, once I changed them two of my tests passed. My third failed with the value "Not found: C# Timer trigger function executed at" but I believe this is because no TimerTrigger is being used in the getCase function.

Comment: In terms of refactoring void to task, is it a simple switch or do i require some other references/extensions etc...Thanks!

Comment: @MD9 simple switch. just change those `void` to `Task` and that should be it. obviously the required `using System.Threading.Tasks;` should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it's missing a reference to your azure functios project, make sure you've added the reference by:

- right clicking your test project
- select the menu Add
- select Reference
- select the projects tab (left menu), then mark the checkbox of your function project
- click ok

Comment: Have repeated this step, it shows that the functions project has been correctly referenced in the references. I am able to call the Functions Project from the Test Project but not the individual Azure Functions within the Functions Project.